# IoT project -- platform io - framework error

Tags: visual-studio-code, iot, esp-idf, platformio

Hi everyone i need help for solving my issue in the platform io when i create new projcet using Platformio framework (espidf)it is still giving me this error and i don't now i can solve this error

note : i intalled git and also chacked all path is correct in my path envirnoment in device in my windows.

here is the screen of error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjzqK.png)

Here this message in details :

PIO Core Call Error: "The current working directory C:\Users\sheha\OneDrive\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\blink will be used for the project.\r\n\r\nThe next files/directories have been created in C:\Users\sheha\OneDrive\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\blink\r\ninclude - Put project header files here\r\nlib - Put here project specific (private) libraries\r\nsrc - Put project source files here\r\nplatformio.ini - Project Configuration File\r\nResolving esp32doit-devkit-v1 dependencies...\r\nAlready up-to-date.\r\nUpdating metadata for the vscode IDE...\r\n\n\nError: Processing esp32doit-devkit-v1 (platform: espressif32; board: esp32doit-devkit-v1; framework: espidf)\r\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\nVerbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option\r\nCONFIGURATION: [https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/espressif32/esp32doit-devkit-v1.html\r\nPLATFORM](https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/espressif32/esp32doit-devkit-v1.html%5Cr%5CnPLATFORM): Espressif 32 (6.1.0) > DOIT ESP32 DEVKIT V1\r\nHARDWARE: ESP32 240MHz, 320KB RAM, 4MB Flash\r\nDEBUG: Current (cmsis-dap) External (cmsis-dap, esp-bridge, esp-prog, iot-bus-jtag, jlink, minimodule, olimex-arm-usb-ocd, olimex-arm-usb-ocd-h, olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h, olimex-jtag-tiny, tumpa)\r\nPACKAGES: \r\n - framework-espidf @ 3.50001.0 (5.0.1) \r\n - tool-cmake @ 3.16.4 \r\n - tool-esptoolpy @ 1.40500.0 (4.5.0) \r\n - tool-idf @ 1.0.1 \r\n - tool-mconf @ 1.4060000.20190628 (406.0.0) \r\n - tool-ninja @ 1.9.0 \r\n - toolchain-esp32ulp @ 1.23500.220830 (2.35.0) \r\n - toolchain-xtensa-esp32 @ 11.2.0+2022r1\r\nReading CMake configuration...\r\n-- Found Git: C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe (found version "2.39.2.windows.1") \r\n-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0\r\n-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0\r\n-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU\r\n-- Found assembler: C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe\r\n-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe\r\n-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe -- works\r\n-- Detecting C compiler ABI info\r\n-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done\r\n-- Detecting C compile features\r\n-- Detecting C compile features - done\r\n-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-g++.exe\r\n-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-g++.exe -- works\r\n-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info\r\n-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done\r\n-- Detecting CXX compile features\r\n-- Detecting CXX compile features - done\r\n-- Project is not inside a git repository, or git repository has no commits; will not use 'git describe' to determine PROJECT_VER.\r\n-- Building ESP-IDF components for target esp32\r\n-- Project sdkconfig file C:/Users/sheha/OneDrive/Documents/PlatformIO/Projects/blink/sdkconfig.esp32doit-devkit-v1\r\n-- Looking for sys/types.h\r\n-- Looking for sys/types.h - found\r\n-- Looking for stdint.h\r\n-- Looking for stdint.h - found\r\n-- Looking for stddef.h\r\n-- Looking for stddef.h - found\r\n-- Check size of time_t\r\n-- Check size of time_t - done\r\n-- Found Python3: C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/penv/.espidf-5.0.1/Scripts/python.exe (found version "3.9.10") found components: Interpreter \r\n-- Performing Test C_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_WFORMAT_SIGNEDNESS\r\n-- Performing Test C_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_WFORMAT_SIGNEDNESS - Success\r\n-- App "blink" version: 1\r\n-- Adding linker script C:/Users/sheha/OneDrive/Documents/PlatformIO/Projects/blink/.pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/esp-idf/esp_system/ld/memory.ld\r\n-- Adding linker script C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_system/ld/esp32/sections.ld.in\r\n-- Adding linker script C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.ld\r\n-- Adding linker script C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.api.ld\r\n-- Adding linker script C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.libgcc.ld\r\n-- Adding linker script C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.newlib-data.ld\r\n-- Adding linker script C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.syscalls.ld\r\n-- Adding linker script C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.newlib-funcs.ld\r\n-- Adding linker script C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/soc/esp32/ld/esp32.peripherals.ld\r\n-- Components: __pio_env app_trace app_update bootloader bootloader_support bt cmock console cxx driver efuse esp-tls esp_adc esp_app_format esp_common esp_eth esp_event esp_gdbstub esp_hid esp_http_client esp_http_server esp_https_ota esp_https_server esp_hw_support esp_lcd esp_local_ctrl esp_netif esp_partition esp_phy esp_pm esp_psram esp_ringbuf esp_rom esp_system esp_timer esp_wifi espcoredump esptool_py fatfs freertos hal heap http_parser idf_test ieee802154 json log lwip mbedtls mqtt newlib nvs_flash openthread partition_table perfmon protobuf-c protocomm pthread sdmmc soc spi_flash spiffs src tcp_transport ulp unity usb vfs wear_levelling wifi_provisioning wpa_supplicant xtensa\r\n-- Component paths: C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/__pio_env C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/app_trace C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/app_update C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/bootloader C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/bootloader_support C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/bt C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/cmock C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/console C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/cxx C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/driver C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/efuse C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp-tls C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_adc C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_app_format C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_common C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_eth C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_event C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_gdbstub C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_hid C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_http_client C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_http_server C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_https_ota C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_https_server C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_hw_support C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_lcd C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_local_ctrl C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_netif C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_partition C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_phy C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_pm C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_psram C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_ringbuf C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_rom C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_system C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_timer C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_wifi C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/espcoredump C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esptool_py C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/fatfs C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/freertos C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/hal C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/heap C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/http_parser C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/idf_test C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/ieee802154 C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/json C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/log C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/lwip C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/mbedtls C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/mqtt C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/newlib C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/nvs_flash C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/openthread C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/partition_table C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/perfmon C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/protobuf-c C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/protocomm C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/pthread C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/sdmmc C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/soc C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/spi_flash C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/spiffs C:/Users/sheha/OneDrive/Documents/PlatformIO/Projects/blink/src C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/tcp_transport C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/ulp C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/unity C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/usb C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/vfs C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/wear_levelling C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/wifi_provisioning C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/wpa_supplicant C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/xtensa\r\n-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!\r\nSee also "C:/Users/sheha/OneDrive/Documents/PlatformIO/Projects/blink/.pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".\r\n\r\nCMake Error at .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/CMakeFiles/git-data/grabRef.cmake:48 (file):\r\n file failed to open for reading (No such file or directory):\r\n\r\n C:/Users/sheha/OneDrive/Documents/PlatformIO/Projects/blink/.pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/CMakeFiles/git-data/head-ref\r\nCall Stack (most recent call first):\r\n C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/tools/cmake/third_party/GetGitRevisionDescription.cmake:80 (include)\r\n C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/tools/cmake/third_party/GetGitRevisionDescription.cmake:90 (get_git_head_revision)\r\n C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/tools/cmake/build.cmake:67 (git_describe)\r\n C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/tools/cmake/build.cmake:219 (__build_get_idf_git_revision)\r\n C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/tools/cmake/idf.cmake:53 (__build_init)\r\n C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/tools/cmake/project.cmake:12 (include)\r\n CMakeLists.txt:2 (include)\r\n\r\n\r\nCMake Error at .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/CMakeFiles/git-data/grabRef.cmake:48 (file):\r\n file failed to open for reading (No such file or directory):\r\n\r\n C:/Users/sheha/OneDrive/Documents/PlatformIO/Projects/blink/.pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/CMakeFiles/git-data/head-ref\r\nCall Stack (most recent call first):\r\n C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/tools/cmake/third_party/GetGitRevisionDescription.cmake:80 (include)\r\n C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/tools/cmake/third_party/GetGitRevisionDescription.cmake:90 (get_git_head_revision)\r\n C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/tools/cmake/project.cmake:61 (git_describe)\r\n C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/tools/cmake/project.cmake:436 (__project_get_revision)\r\n CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)\r\n\r\n\r\nfatal: Needed a single revision\r\nfatal: not a git repository: C:/Users/sheha/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/openthread/openthread/../../../.git/modules/components/openthread/openthread\r\n\r\n========================= [FAILED] Took 20.09 seconds ========================="